# Are Python Empty Immutables Singletons?

Tags: python, types, singleton, immutability

Are Python Empty Immutables Singletons?

If you review the CPython implementation of builtin types, you'll find comments on all the immutable builtin objects that their empty versions are singletons. This would make a lot of sense as Python could avoid wasting memory on redundant items that would never change in place.

[Here, specifically, is the source for 2.6 that references frozensets.](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/23a60d89dbd4/Objects/setobject.c#l1036) It declares as a comment:

```
/* The empty frozenset is a singleton */
```

I find the same comment in CPython 2.5 as well. I think it makes sense to refer to the source in addition to the documentation because CPython is the reference implementation of Python.

I'm using Python 2.6.5, and I get the following result in my interpreter:

```
>>> g = frozenset()
>>> f = frozenset('a') - frozenset('a')
>>> f
frozenset([])
>>> f is g
False
>>> id(f)
279262312
>>> id(g)
114734544
```

Does this mean that the comment is wrong? Is this a bug in 2.6.5? Is this guaranteed in later versions of Python? If so, I can't find reference to it in the documentation.

I ask this because I need a check that was identical to membership in `(None, '')`, but the reason is another story.

Is this why it's considered best practice to use `is` to check for `None`, and to use `==` or Python's semantic Falsiness of empty types for control flow relating to other types?

To sum up:

Are Python's empty immutables ever guaranteed to be singletons?

Comment: The source code you reference that `frozenset()` is a singleton while `frozenset(iterable)` is always a new object, even when `iterable` turns out to be empty. Plus the fact that it's a comment in the source code of one implementation, not a remark in documentation, adds up to: No guarantee and no point in worrying about it.

Comment: @delnan In addition to that, digging through the C code, `frozenset` actually uses `set` 's rich compare methods, as well as using `set_difference_multi` for it's difference method, which all create new set instances for the result no matter what inputs they get.  Since OP's triggering `__sub__` under the covers, the empty singleton optimization in `frozenset_new` is completely irrelevant.

Comment: The behavior that OP discovered empirically and @SilasRay and delnan discovered analytically means that the comment, ["*The empty frozenset is a singleton*"](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/23a60d89dbd4/Objects/setobject.c#l1036) is, at best, misleading and, in my opinion, just wrong.

Comment: @Robᵩ It just demonstrates that comments /= documentation.  The comment is locally accurate in the context of the `frozenset_new` function, but not globally applicable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [description of standard types](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) makes no promise that equivalent objects are identical, except for `True`, `False`, `None`, `NotImplemented`, and `Ellipsis`. Some of the promises that it does **not** make are`() is ()`, nor `1 is 1`, nor `'hello' is 'hello'`. (In fact, the documentation specifically **denies** the requirement `1 is 1` in the final paragraph of 3.1.)

No, Python's empty immutable containers are not guaranteed to be singletons<sup>*</sup>. The only guaranteed singletons are `True`, `False`, `None`, `NotImplemented`, and `Ellipsis`.

---

<sup>*</sup> Note: the word "*singleton*" in this context is used other than in its generally accepted meaning. In this post, singleton means a value that can be held by only one object; it follows that every object containing that value is identical.

Comment: Plus one on noting the emphatic statement that `1 is 1` is not guaranteed, (should probably link to it), and the guaranteed NotImplemented and Ellipsis, I noticed them too.

Comment: Shouldn't `True` and `False` be considered singletons, as well?

Comment: "The two objects representing the values False and True are the only Boolean objects."  Yep. Thanks, @JimmyC

Comment: @JimmyC Technically, a singleton is a class that can have only one instance, and since `True` and `False` are both `bool` type, they are by definition not singletons.  I'm not sure they are guaranteed by spec to be globally unique instances, but they do appear to act like borgs, at least in C Python.

Comment: @SilasRay - While that is the correct definition, that isn't the definition that OP had in mind when he said "singleton." I am using OP's definition, which is more like "a value which can only be held by a single object."